# FFT. Correlation between frequency and time samples

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft

what is a correlation between time samples and frequency?

I have 250 samples that correspond to **1 second** of my signal(for specific point) and 500 samples to **2 seconds** respectively. Main formula of frequency is f = 1/T. Hence, the more time samples i have, the less my freq should be i think.

Code:

```
#frequence
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
pointdat=tracesM[361,28*250:(28+2)*250]
this = np.fft.fft(pointdat-np.mean(pointdat))
thisi = int(len(this))
thisii = np.abs(this[:(thisi)])
print(max(thisii))
plt.plot(thisii)
plt.grid(color='black')
plt.title('2s for specific point(361 in this situation)')
plt.xlabel('number of time samples(frequency?)')
plt.ylabel('power')
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=20)
locY = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=10)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(locY)
plt.show()
```

I've got the charts:
 1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i6cc.png)
 2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAS3V.png)

As i know i should get the dependence of power(of signal) and frequency in the charts using np.fft.fft. But it looks like i'm getting the dependence of power(of signal) and time samples: 250 and 500 samples corresponding to 1 and 2 seconds respectively.

**The main questions: 
 1. What dependence i get at these charts?
 2. What is the value of T(period) at these charts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dt is the timestep, df is the frequency step and N is the number of samples, then we have for the discrete Fourier transform

```
dt*df = 2*pi/N
```

If T is the total sampling length, we have

```
dt = T/N
df = 2*pi/T
```

Figure out your df and multiply your frequency axis by df.